# $A \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y) \implies A^* \in \mathcal{L}(Y^*_{w^*}, X^*_{w^*})$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-topology

**Exercise :**

> Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and $A \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$. Show that $ A^* \in \mathcal{L}(Y^*_{w^*}, X^*_{w^*})$.

**Attempt :**

The linearity is trivial. Τo show that $A^*$ is $w^*$ to $w^*$ continuous :

Let $g_n \xrightarrow{w^*} g \in Y^*$. For any $x \in X$ it is $A(x) \in Y$ which implies :

$$\langle A^*(g_n), x\rangle = \langle g_n, A(x)\rangle \xrightarrow{w^*} \langle g,A(x)\rangle=\langle A^*(g),x\rangle$$

Thus, it is $A^*(g_n) \xrightarrow{w^*} A^*(g)$, which means that $A^*$ is $w^*$ to $w^*$ continuous.

**Q :** About boundedness, how does one imply that as we're working over metric spaces equipped with the weak* topology ? Is it enough to show that they are w* to w* continuous since the adjoint operator of a bounded operator is bounded anyway ? Any inputs will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any notation you want as long as you define it. Without explicitly defining $\mathcal{L}(\cdot, \cdot)$ is often used to denote bounded linear operators from a Banach space to another. $C(M,N)$ is a notation that is widespread to denote continuous functions from $M$ to $N$. One could use $C(Y_{w^*}^*,X_{w^*}^*)$. There are some books that use $C$ for closed operators, or compact. The best option is always to define explicitly the notation.

If you want to prove that $A^*:Y_{w^*}^*\to X_{w^*}^*$ is continuous when the weak-$*$ topologies of $Y^*$ and $X^*$ are used, then you can do similar to what you did, except that you should use [nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)) instead of sequences.

If $g_{\alpha}\in Y^*$ is a net converging to $g\in Y^*$ in the weak-$*$ topology, then $\forall y\in Y$ $g_\alpha(y)\to g(y)$ as a net in $\mathbb{C}$.

Then $A^{*}(g_\alpha)\in X^*$ and for all $x\in X$

$$A^{*}(g_\alpha)(x)=g_\alpha(A(x))\to g(A(x))=A^*(g)(x)$$

Therefore $A^*(g_\alpha)$ converges to $A^*(g)$ in the weak-$*$ topology of $X^*$.

This is the same argument you did, except with the clarification that we are using nets instead of just sequences, and using the functional notation instead of the bracket notation, but that is is only because it takes me more time to type the $\langle$ and $\rangle$.

The need for nets instead of sequences is due to the weak-$*$ topology not being necessarily first-countable. This can happen, for example, if $X$ and/or $Y$ have uncountable dimension.

---

**Proof that continuous implies bounded**

This is general for any continuous linear transformation between locally convex topological vector spaces.

Since $A^*$ is continuous, for every $x\in X$ and $e>0$, there is a finite number of $y_1,...,y_n\in Y$ and $e_1,...,e_n>0$ such that $A^*(\bigcup_{i=1}^n\{y^*:\ |y^*(y_i)|<e_i\})\subset \{x^*:\ |x^*(x)|<e\}$.

This means that $\forall i=1,...,n, |y^*(y_i)|<\min_{i\in\{1,..,n\}}(e_i)$ implies $|A^*(y^*)(x)|<e$.

Therefore, scaling the $y^*$ we get $$|A^*(y^*)(x)|\leq \frac{e}{\min_{i\in\{1,..,n\}}e_i}\max_{i\in\{1,..,n\}}|y^*(y_i)|$$

Comment: This is true for an adjoint operator, as mentioned. What does $\| \cdot \|_{Y^*_{w^*}}$ mean ? There isn't a norm in the weak* topology.

Comment: $Y^*_{w^*}$ is the dual space of $Y$ equipped with the weak* topology.

Comment: Yes, the notation $\mathcal{L}$ indeed denotes that. But since an adjoint operator of a linear bounded is always bounded, in order to show that it also belongs in the space of bounded linear functionals between spaces that are described by only the weak* topology, isn't it enough to show that they preserve continuity ? Weak* topology is a smaller topology than the norm topology that implies boundedness in common terms. We cannot have a norm there.

Comment: Thus my initial intuition involving the addition of $w^*$ to $w^*$ continuity is indeed the trick for the specific problem ? Always taking into account that $A^*$ is bounded.

Comment: The notation mentioned indeed means : the linear bounded operators from $X^*_{w^*}$ to $Y^*_{w^*}$. What I am arguing is that a space equipped with the weak* topology does not have a norm, otherwise we are talking about a norm topology. Hence, what I said, is thats ince we know that the adjoint operator of a bounded linear operator with respect to the norms induced by the norm-strong duals is bounded, then it suffices to show that we have the continuity.

Comment: Also, the way you initially handled the question is just the same as ignoring the weak* aspect, which makes no sense.

Comment: @Rebellos You need to use nets. Your proof with sequences is not enough. Whether you want to assume that bounded with respect to the family of seminorms $\|x^*\|_x=|x^*(x)|$ is equivalent to continuity or not is up to you. A complete proof would need to include it.

Comment: @Rebellos The confusion is because you don't define your notation.

Comment: We simplify it to the use of sequences as we do not use nets. But my question as it initialy was is this : Is w* to w* continuity enough to impli the boundedness ? My notation is the standard one, it describes the bounded linear operators from the one space to another which are also equipped with the w* topology.

Comment: @Rebellos One cannot skip using nets. Since sending sending convergent sequences to convergent sequences doesn't imply continuity in spaces that are not first-countable.

Comment: We do not use nets as we haven't been taught of them. We know that it is essentialy wrong but we rely ona simplified intuition based on sequences on such cases. But my question is still not answered. How does one properly show that $A^*$ belongs in the set of linear bounded operators between the duals of $X,Y$ equipped with the weak* topology ?

Comment: @Rebellos Added the proof that continuous linear transformation between locally convex topological vector spaces are bounded with respect to the family of semi-norms. You mentioned 'metric spaces'. Which is not true in general. Taking into account the assumptions that you are making about not using nets, it looks like maybe you are assuming only separable spaces. In that case, you can pass from the boundedness with respect to the family of semi-norms to the metric defined by $d(x_1^*,x_2^*)=\sum_{i=1}^n2^{-i}|x_1^*(x_i)-x_2^*(x_i)|$ for some $x_i$ dense in the unit ball.

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy but constructive chat !